# Starting Linux from USB pen drive

Tags: boot, usb-drive

Does starting Linux from USB pen drive delete anything on hard drive?

Comment: For future questions: "Linux" is just the operating system "kernel", the part that talks to your computer's hardware. Normally, you will be using a "Linux *distribution*" that combines this kernel with software that you can actually interact with as a normal user. Therefore you'll have normally have to tell us what *distribution* (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, …) you are using so we can give meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on *what exactly* you're booting from your USB drive.

**In general**, anything you boot from a USB drive, CD, or other boot medium has complete control over your computer and all its devices (hard disk, network interface, etc), so you'll want to make sure you only use boot media from a source you trust to not be malicious.

**In your case**, I *assume* you're talking about Linux "live CDs" like the ones provided by Ubuntu, Arch Linux, and just about any other major Linux distribution.
Those don't just contain the Linux kernel, but also include a set of programs that provides features like a shell to run commands from, or a graphical user interface.
As the name implies, these "live" CDs boot into an independent environment that runs straight from the boot medium (and vanishes when you unplug the USB drive or eject the CD).
Unless you specifically tell them to do something to your hard drive, they won't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

**Overview:**

Before using a Live USB or CD, you should have an understanding of what it is, and how it works. The answer to your question, however, depends on YOU. Meaning a Live USB can have the power to be used without it affecting your host machine, or it can be used to completely erase it, or diagnose it (If you have a virus, malware, or need to recover files).

**How do Live USB Pen Drives work:**

When you boot your computer, it normally boots the operating system located on its hard drive. However, computers can also boot operating systems located on other devices. For example, when you install Linux, your computer boots from a CD, DVD, or USB stick, loads the Linux installer, and installs Linux onto your hard drive.

**Does it change your host machine?**

Live Linux systems — either live CDs or USB drives — take advantage of this feature to run entirely from a CD or USB stick. When you insert the USB drive or CD into your computer and restart, your computer will boot from that device. The live environment works **entirely** in your computer’s RAM, **writing nothing to disk**. When you’re done, you can reboot your computer and remove the USB drive or disc. The computer will be left **exactly as it was**.

**Warning:**

Like I said before, the answer to your question really only depends on YOU. As long as you don't change the state of your host machine within the Live USB, such as mess with partitions, or move files in your Host directories, then your machine will be exactly the way it was after you're done using the USB.